# How to get the current hashRate in geth?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I started geth on mainnet
I did miner.start()
it logs when generating the DAG  , getting block headers ...etc
but when i do `eth.hashrate` it logs 0
also  when i do `miner.getHashRate()` or `miner.HashRate` it throws an error saying that the function is undefined
It happened before , and the account balance keeps infcreasing
Is it a problem ?
How can I get the current Hashrate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your hashrate with `eth.hashrate` or `miner.hashrate`, the result is in H/s (Hash operations per second).

```
> eth.hashrate
712000
```

If it shows `0` it means the following:

- either you are GPU mining: Geth an only report the hashrate of the internal CPU miner
- or you are synchronizing the chain: the miner does not start until you are full synchronized
- or you are generating a DAG file for the miner: the miner does not start until the DAG generation for the latest epoch is complete
- or you just started mining very recently: the miner takes some minutes to compute the latest hashrate